# Calling an external API with a Node application (KeystoneJS)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, xmlhttprequest, keystonejs

I'm newer to Node and trying to learn how to modify my Keystone.JS app so it can call data from an API (JSON or XML) and display it in the view that is rendered.

The current code in my app is essentially a cloned version of this demo app https://github.com/JedWatson/keystone-demo except the view engine is Handlebars in my app. What I have tried to so far is is installing the request package and played around with code from the documentation in a my keystone.js file with no luck.

Then I created a model/api.js file, routes/api.js, routes/views/api.js and templates/views/api.hbs and again played with code examples in the request documentation but failed to even grasp what I was doing and how all of these new pages even worked within my app.

I would greatly appreciate figuring out how to call an API and display the requested info in one of the apps rendered views. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could hit the api from your model logic like so https://github.com/r3dm/shpe-sfba/blob/master/models/Event.js#L69 You could use node's built in http library http://devdocs.io/node/http

```
// Below we call the Facebook api to fill in data for our model
Event.schema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var myEvent = this;

    var apiCall = 'your API string';

    https.get(apiCall, function(res) {
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(d) { body += d; });
        res.on('end', function() {
        body = JSON.parse(body);

        if (body.error) {
            var err = new Error('There was an error saving your changes. Make sure the Facebook Event is set to "Public" and try again');
            next(err);
        } else {
            next();
        });
    })
    .on('error', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
});
```

If you want the data to be fetched in some other scenario try adding the http request to `initLocals` in `routes/middleware.js`.

Comment: Thanks Harry, I will give this a try this evening.